# GSM Signal Strength Retrieval in Android

Tags: android, signals, android-permissions

I'm retrieving the cellular signal strength by listening to the signal strengths using the phone listener

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

telephonyManager.listen(psListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
```

I want to ask if it's possible to retrieve the signal in an alternative way (without requesting the read phone state permission).

Please help

Comment: any help in here?

Answer (score 0):

> CellInfoGsm class Contains
>
> Immutable cell information from a point in time.
>
> CellSignalStrengthGsm
>          getCellSignalStrength()
>
> CellSignalStrengthGsm     contains GSM signal strength related
>   information.
>
> Methods  int  getAsuLevel() Get the signal level as an asu value
>   between 0..31, 99 is unknown Asu is calculated based on 3GPP RSRP.
>
> int   getDbm() Get the signal strength as dBm
>
> int   getLevel() Get signal level as an int from 0..4
>
> int   getTimingAdvance() Get the GSM timing advance between 0..219
>   symbols (normally 0..63).

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```

Comment: getAllCellInfo() returns a null value, and getNeighbouringInfo() has been deprecated since API 7